# Increasing understanding - copying arrays with the spread operator while inside a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two versions of the same function that I have defined, `copyMachine` which takes `arr` (an array) and `num` (a number) as arguments. The function is supposed to return a new array made up of num copies of `arr`.

What I don't understand is why a multidimensional array is not ouput and instead a single array is output in the first code block below? What is the wrong with the code? I really need to make an effort to understand why.

From what I understand `newArr` reinitialises with every new iteration of the while loop. In this context does the word reinitialise mean to reset the array so it is empty? Is there a way to see this with `console.log()` ?

Finally when we reinitialise an array in a loop in this specific case does that mean we can not build a multidimensional array?

```
function copyMachine(arr, num) {
  let newArr = [];
  while (num >= 1) {
    newArr = [...arr];
    num--;
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Then I also have this code block which has the simple addition of the `.push` method within the loop. This seems to allow a multidimensional array to be built. I do not understand why this prevents the issue above whereby `newArr` will reinitialise with every iteration.

```
function copyMachine(arr, num) {
  let newArr = [];
  while (num >= 1) {
    newArr.push([...arr]);
    num--;
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the first bit of code, you are continually overwriting the array. So, the loop is irrelevant, the code is equivalent to `if (num >= 1) newArr = [...arr]`

Comment: `newArr.push` never overwrites the `newArr` array, but adds elements (the new arrays) to it

Comment: @VLAZ can I just ask you to expand when you say continually overwriting? Do you mean on each console.log() or inside the function?

Comment: @user1554264 because `newArr = [...arr]` overwrites the old value of `newArr`. Since it's in a loop, by "continually", I mean "every loop iteration".

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in the first case every loop iteration overwrites `newArr`. You can see this here when the values are logged before and after:

```js
function copyMachine(arr, num) {
  console.log(`copyMachine called with
   num: ${num}
   arr: ${formatForDisplay(arr)}`)
  let newArr = [];
  while (num >= 1) {
    console.log(`-> start of loop --
      newArr: ${formatForDisplay(newArr)}
      num: ${num}`);
    newArr = [...arr];
    num--;
    
    console.log(`<- end of loop --
      newArr: ${formatForDisplay(newArr)}
      num: ${num}`);
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(copyMachine(["a", "b", "c"], 3)); //some copies
console.log(copyMachine(["a", "b", "c"], 0)); //no copies

//just for logging
function formatForDisplay(val) {
  if (!Array.isArray(val)) return String(val);
  return `[${val.map(formatForDisplay)}]`
}
```

Since every iteration *ignores* the value from the previous iteration, the output is equivalent to the following:

```js
function copyMachine(arr, num) {
  let newArr = [];
  if (num >= 1) {
    newArr = [...arr];
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(copyMachine(["a", "b", "c"], 3)); //some copies
console.log(copyMachine(["a", "b", "c"], 0)); //no copies
```

If you want to *preserve* the value of the previous iteration you can either 
 - *change* but not overwrite the previous value. The second code does this with [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) this *adds* values to the existing array.
 - create a new array that is based on the previous one and includes the new one. Using spread syntax, you can do it this way:

```js
function copyMachine(arr, num) {
  console.log(`copyMachine called with
   num: ${num}
   arr: ${formatForDisplay(arr)}`)
  let newArr = [];
  while (num >= 1) {
    console.log(`-> start of loop --
      newArr: ${formatForDisplay(newArr)}
      num: ${num}`);
    newArr = [
      ...newArr, //make a copy of the previous newArr
      [ // and add a new array
        ...arr //that has a copy of `arr`
      ]
    ];
    num--;
    
    console.log(`<- end of loop --
      newArr: ${formatForDisplay(newArr)}
      num: ${num}`);
  }
  return newArr;
}


console.log(copyMachine(["a", "b", "c"], 3)); //some copies
console.log(copyMachine(["a", "b", "c"], 0)); //no copies

//just for logging
function formatForDisplay(val) {
  if (!Array.isArray(val)) return String(val);
  return `[${val.map(formatForDisplay)}]`
}
```

You can also use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for a similar result instead of spread syntax:

```js
function copyMachine(arr, num) {
  console.log(`copyMachine called with
   num: ${num}
   arr: ${formatForDisplay(arr)}`)
  let newArr = [];
  while (num >= 1) {
    console.log(`-> start of loop --
      newArr: ${formatForDisplay(newArr)}
      num: ${num}`);
    newArr = newArr.concat( //make a new array that is a copy of the previous one
      [ //which includes another array
        arr.slice() //that contains a copy of `arr`
      ]
    )
    num--;
    
    console.log(`<- end of loop --
      newArr: ${formatForDisplay(newArr)}
      num: ${num}`);
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(copyMachine(["a", "b", "c"], 3));
console.log(copyMachine(["a", "b", "c"], 0));

//just for logging
function formatForDisplay(val) {
  if (!Array.isArray(val)) return String(val);
  return `[${val.map(formatForDisplay)}]`
}
```

Note that similar to just using spread syntax, you have to make a new array that has a copy of the previous one. [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is a non-spread syntax to make a copy of an array.

Answer (score -1):

This line is incorrect in your solution:

```
newArr = [...arr];
```

each time you say *get all elements from `arr` and create new array, save it to `newArr` variable*

Try it:

```
newArr = [...newArr, [...arr]];
```

Your `newArr` won't be cleaned and you will add new array to those that already exist.

Answer (score -1):

newArr = [...arr];
 This line copies the arr value to newArr, here you are assigning the arr value to new Arr
 From your requirement (to create copies of arr) you need to generate a new array and keep adding arr as a new item in newarr which is occuring in the second function 
ie >> newArr.push([...arr]);

Spread operator is used to copy the values of a source array/object to a target source/object. When the target object is edited the source object is not effected and vice-versa